# How to press (Ctrl+T) in selenium-webdriver on Ubuntu (Firefox)?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, ubuntu-18.04

I want to open a new tab in an existing browser, but in ubuntu(os) with firefox, it's not working.

I have tried both actions and robot class but still, I am unable to do it.

```
driver.get("http://www.google.com/");
driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
System.out.println(driver.getTitle());
Robot robot = new Robot();
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_T);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_T);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
```

Also, have tried the below code,

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();         
driver.get("http://www.google.com/");           
driver.manage().Timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);           
System.out.println(driver.getTitle());
Actions act = new Actions(driver);  
act.keyDown(Keys.CONTROL).sendKeys("t").keyUp(Keys.CONTROL).build().perform();
driver.get("http://www.bing.com/");
System.out.println(driver.getTitle());
act.keyDown(Keys.CONTROL).sendKeys("t").keyUp(Keys.CONTROL).build().perform();
driver.get("http://www.yahoo.com/");    
System.out.println(driver.getTitle());
```

After using both the above code still, a new tab is not getting opened.
Can anyone help me with this??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use JavaScript Executor to open a new tab.

```
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("window.open()");
List<String> tabs = new ArrayList<String>(driver.getWindowHandles());
driver.switchTo().window(tabs.get(1));
```

Comment: "ArrayList cannot be resolved to a type "  using this code I am getting this error what import is needed to resolve this error

Comment: Please refer to the updated code above and import `java.util`